# Annual income and monthly income for self-employed person for UK standard visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, pakistani-citizens

Last month I applied for a UK visitor visa as I have booked a booth in exhibition and fully paid off for my booth. But unfortunately I got my visa refused. The visa officer was not satisfied on my bank statements saying that the funds are not accessible for you. Even I attached 2 of my business statements and 1 of my personal statement.
I transfer 380000 PKR from my business account to my personal account. I put ed annual income 4.5 million PKR annually and I stated I spend 80000 PKR per month. Anyone can guide me where I did made a mistake?

Comment: Did you provide your most recent tax return, and financial statements demonstrating eg your business’ debtors & creditors and its profitability? Is the 4.5m PKR *turnover* or profit? Do the bank statements prove a history of 80,000PKR minimum drawings monthly from the business?